# android zxing integration

Tags: android, zxing

Im trying to integrate zxing barcode scanner into my app.  I am not wanting to do it via an intent as i would like the app to be an all in one solution.  I understand the limitations this has but i dont really have an option on this one

i have followed the following guide to integrate the code as a library into my project

http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

I am receiving a Null exception error with the following logcat .  If anyone knows much about the zxing code could give me any pointers  that would be great.  let me know if you require any more background info

.  I am calling the scaner with the following

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);



12-28 06:41:57.464: W/dalvikvm(4301): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aaca450)
12-28 06:41:57.464: E/AndroidRuntime(4301): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.discovery_scan.app/com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2950)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2965)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2516)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:885)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.onResume(CaptureActivity.java:178)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1149)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3763)
12-28 06:41:57.504: E/AndroidRuntime(4301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
```

Comment: Did you modify any part of the zxing source? What device are you using? Does the Market version of Barcode Scanner work correctly? Is the market version installed on the device while you are testing your own build? (if so I would try uninstalling that first);

Comment: Hi,  No i have not altered the zxing code at all left as is.  I have tried my project ( with the zxing library code ) on 2 devices and getting the same error.

Comment: @user1096447  have u found solution gettingsame error ?

Answer (score 2):

The biggest confusion here is that you are trying to not use Intents, but, you are using Intents. Which is it?

I assume you are not actually wanting to use Intents. The error comes because you have copied and pasted our code without understanding it. I am sure it is because the onResume() method refers to UI elements that are not found in your copy of the layout.

Please don't copy our code like this; in fact a complete copy violates trademark, I think. Integrate via Intent if you don't have the time or inclination to write your own scanner app.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: Hi, im sorry i never relised . I only started coding for android couple of weeks ago so its my naivety im afraid I had a look at your code to perform this via "intents" I created a new activity in my project called IntentIntegrator using the code you provided ( only chaning the package name at the top ) I am getting the following error however or the line
    public static IntentResult parseActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

it says "IntentResult cannot be resolved to a type" i may just be being stupid but do you know what this means?

Comment: You need both classes from android-integration